# How to delete rows which can't be cast to INT

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have this sample table with a housenumber in my postgresql 9.1:

```
drop table if exists mytable;
create table mytable(road_id int, housenr text);
insert into mytable(road_id, housenr) values

('11', '1' ),
('22', '12' ), 
('33', '99/1' ),
('44', '88' ),
('55', '2' ),
('66', '28' ),
('77', '29')
;
```

Now I have to convert the whole column "housenr" into an INT field. Is there a way in SQL to cast only these rows from the column which can be casted. In mytable this would be every row except the one with "housenr" = 99/1.
Something like: FOR EACH ROW IF ::int IS POSSIBLE cast the row ELSE REMOVE FROM TABLE

Comment: Does that field *have* to be an `int`? You define it as `text`...

Comment: But `99/1` could be a valid house number.

Comment: I have to calculate these numbers in a further step (subtract them from each other). Every field-type would be ok in which I can perform these calculations. @ bluefeet: this doesn't matter. If you could convert 99/1 into 99 it would perfect to

Comment: casting `99/1` to int should give you `99` anyways. don't know if it's true of postgres, but mysql does have a 'strict' mode that would forbid such a cast and simply give you a null.

Comment: this is the error message: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "99/1"
SQL Status:22P02

Comment: @C.B. what will you want if the `housenr` has an alpha character in it?  for example `105/a`, what result do you want?

Comment: In MySQL you could do `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE CAST(housenr AS UNSIGNED) = 0`. Isn't that what you want? I think CAST() is standard SQL.

Comment: @AndreKR they are looking for postgresql, not mysql

Comment: @JasonHeine And by that you mean Postgresql did not implement `CAST()` or what?

Comment: @MarcB Egads, no, casting `99/1` to `integer` should produce an error, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use REGEX to evaluate your column values to determine if it is numeric:

```
select * FROM MyTable where (housenr !~ '^[0-9]+$')
```

Here is the SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d2ff3/9

Here is the Postgresql documentation on ~ and ~!

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE

Comment: +1 Great this works for all scenarios to avoid anything other than digits :)

Comment: @JasonHeine why don't you add the `cast()` int here as well makes the answer crytal perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You may do a `case when`

```
select * from (
    select roadid, case when 
    instr(housenr,"/") > 0 then 0 else cast(housenr as int) end) as housenr_new
    from mytable) t
where t.housenr_new <> 0
    ;
```

Using a `regex` with case when to return a 0 when the field is not `int`

```
SELECT roadid, CASE WHEN housenr ~ E'^\\d+$' 
THEN housenr::integer ELSE 0 END as housenr_new
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: @C.B. the above code is provided really assuming that your *removable* `house number` comes with a `/`. If you need more special characters to be inspected then rather use a `regex` ;)